Getting 'Failed To Fetch' error on everycall with development database with heroku with a react app and java springboot backend and mysql database
I have hosted my frontend and backend on heroku. I setup a mysql database through heroku and just pushed up my version that is pointing at the deployment database and links. My database is full with data and setup.
However on my app I get a failed to fetch error every call.
So I got a couple of questions I guess.

Currently my application.properties is in my .gitignore. Do I need to take that out so that my heroku environment can see the links?

How would I trouble shoot this? Postman never responds with a call.

Did I set it up correctly?


Call on the frontend:
const fetchUsers = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://ec2-34-225-27-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/users');
            if (response.ok) {
                const userData = await response.json();
                setUsers(userData);
            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch users');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
        }
    };

Application.properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-34-225-27-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dadlhgoflf7mau
spring.datasource.username=REDACTED
spring.datasource.password=REDACTED
keycloak.realm=jcmm
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

Credentials provided by Heroku
Host
ec2-34-225-27-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Database
dadlhgoflf7mau
User
REDACTED
Port
5432
Password
REDACTED
URI
postgres://username:password@ec2-34-225-27-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dadlhgoflf7mau


I am expected just clean calls. Most of them are just calls that pull the whole table.
I have tried multiple different configurations of the application.properties.


You shouldn't put your application.properties in .gitignore. heroku needs it to access important credentials and the properties file will contain important dynamic application related information.

Heroku Credentials are being rotated frequently, so hardcoding them can cause you to frequently lookup the updated credentials and change in your app to do development. On heroku when you deploy a database, it creates a few enviroment variables like:


spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}


Providing a driver is no longer neccessary
[IMPROTANT]Your fetching URI seems to be incorrect. Instead of the database URI, you have to include the URL of the deployed application. It should look something like, appname.herokuapp.com

